High GVIF in GAM
I keep getting a high GVIF (with INF), after my GAM analysis, I have combined levels for most of my categorical variables. I have also removed some variables but still, the high GVIF keeps occurring. please i need help. below is my code, I am a newbaby so my code might look somehow. I applied smooth for my continuous variables only.
gam_model <- gam(log_HDDS~        s(log_obesogenic_share, k = 10) +  
                                  s(sec_asset, k = 12) +  
                                  s(SSIrecalcrounded, k = 7) +
                                  s(House_h_age, k =8) +
                                  s(time_to_clst_mrkt, k = 7) +
                                  s(hh_mem_no, k = 7) +
                                  s(educ, k = 7) +
                   factor(buying_food_who_grouped) +
                   factor(Marital_status) +
                   factor(loan) +
                   factor(ration_card_grouped) +
                   factor(main_occ_grouped) +
                   factor(Caste_Grouped) +
                   factor(transect_id) ,
                 family = gaussian(link = "identity"),
                 method = "REML",  
                 select = TRUE,    
                 paraPen = list(log_obesogenic_share =list(diag(1)),
                                sec_asset= list(diag(1)),
                                SSIrecalcrounded = list(diag(1)),
                                House_h_age = list(diag(1)),
                                time_to_clst_mrkt = list(diag(1)),
                                hh_mem_no = list(diag(1)),
                                educ= list(diag(1))),  
                 data = diet_data)

And here is my GVIF result:
vif(gam_model)
                                        GVIF Df GVIF^(1/(2*Df))
factor(buying_food_who_grouped) 1.025172e+25  0             Inf
factor(Marital_status)          1.025172e+25  0             Inf
factor(loan)                    1.025172e+25  0             Inf
factor(ration_card_grouped)     1.025172e+25  0             Inf
factor(main_occ_grouped)        1.025172e+25  0             Inf
factor(Caste_Grouped)           1.025172e+25  0             Inf
factor(transect_id)             1.025172e+25  0             Inf
log_obesogenic_share            1.025172e+25  0             Inf
sec_asset                       1.025172e+25  0             Inf
SSIrecalcrounded                1.025172e+25  0             Inf
House_h_age                     1.025172e+25  0             Inf
time_to_clst_mrkt               1.025172e+25  0             Inf
hh_mem_no                       1.025172e+25  0             Inf
educ                            1.025172e+25  0             Inf


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It doesn't really make sense to consider GVIF in the context of GAMs, particularly anything that involves splines (I'm not sure what is going on with the output given the clearly erroneous values, but I'm guessing this is partly because mgcv models don't work with whatever you're using on it). What you would be more chiefly concerned with is concurvity, which is the GAM equivalent to collinearity. One can easily check this by using the following code on your model:
concurvity(gam_model)

As for if this is an actual concern in your model, you can consider applying techniques like dimension reduction (to collapse the troublesome variables into a simpler structure) or some form of regularization for your GAM (which penalizes terms to simplify the model, what I assume you attempted with the select = TRUE here). You anyway have a lot of terms in your model and its not clear how much data you have, so it may serve some use to simplify your model some.

Thanks you @Shawn Hemelstrand for your answer. I will focus more on Concurvity as advised, because I have also tried to penalize the variables in the model (GAM), but VIF is still very high. I don't need to waste my time bothering about VIF in GAM.
